# Angular dataService.init is not a function when trying to call rest function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

Currently I'm learning AngularJS. I practicing it by doing a Quiz app tutorial. I got stuck because after I injecting one of my factory into one of my controller... I couldn't call the factory's rest function...
My JSON data is come from a Spring backend.

results.js:

```
(function(){

    angular
        .module("quizApp")
        .controller("resultsController", resultsController);

    resultsController.$inject = ['quizMetrics', 'dataService'];

    function resultsController(quizMetrics, dataService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.quizMetrics = quizMetrics;
        vm.dataService = dataService;
        vm.activeQuestion = 0;
        vm.reset = reset;
        vm.getAnswerClass = getAnswerClass;
        vm.setActiveQuestion = setActiveQuestion;
        vm.calculatePerc = calculatePerc;

        function getAnswerClass(index) {
            if(index === quizMetrics.correctAnswers[vm.activeQuestion]) {
                return "bg-success";
            } else if (index === dataService.quizQuestions[vm.activeQuestion].selected){
                return "bg-danger";
            }
        }

        function setActiveQuestion(index){
            vm.activeQuestion = index;
        }

        function calculatePerc() {
            return quizMetrics.numCorrect / dataService.quizQuestions.length * 100;
        }

        function reset() {
            dataService.init();
            quizMetrics.changeState("results", false);
            quizMetrics.numCorrect = 0;

            for(var i = 0; i < dataService.quizQuestions.length; i++) {
                var data = dataService.quizQuestions[i];

                data.selected = null;
                data.correct = null;
            }
        }

    }

})();
```

dataService.js:

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module("quizApp")
        .factory("dataService", DataFactory);

    function DataFactory($http) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.init = init;
        vm.getAllQ = getAllQ;

        init();

        function init(){
            getAllQ();
        }

        var dataObj = {
            quizData: quizData,
            quizQuestions: [],
            correctAnswers: []
        };

        function getAllQ(){
            var url = "/tenQuestion";
            var questionsPromise = $http.get(url);
            questionsPromise.then(function(response){
                dataObj.quizQuestions = response.data;

                for(var i = 0; i < dataObj.quizQuestions.length; i++) {
                    /*console.log("[LOG]: "+ i +". quizQuestions.solution: " + dataObj.quizQuestions[i].solution);
                    console.log("[LOG]: "+ i +". quizQuestions.solution: " + response.data[i].solution);*/
                    dataObj.correctAnswers.push(response.data[i].solution);
                }

            });
        }

        return dataObj;
    }
})();
```

game.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="quizApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>GAME Page - KRESZ QUIZ</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>



<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="page-header">
        <form th:action="@{/questions}" method="get">
            <button class="btn btn-md btn-warning btn-block" type="Submit">Go Question Page</button>
        </form>

        <form th:action="@{/answers}" method="get">
            <button class="btn btn-md btn-warning btn-block" type="Submit">Go Answer Page</button>
        </form>


        <h1>KRESZ Quiz</h1>
        <h3>
            KRESZ tanulást segítő <strong>quiz</strong> alkalmazás
        </h3>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="listController as list" ng-hide="list.quizMetrics.quizActive || list.quizMetrics.resultsActive">
        <form class="form-inline well well-sm clearfix"  >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Keres..."
                    class="form-control"
                    ng-model="list.search">


            <button class="btn btn-warning pull-right" ng-click="list.activateQuiz()">
                <strong>Start Quiz</strong>
            </button>

            <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right" method="get" th:href="@{/logout}">
                <strong>Logout</strong>
            </a>
        </form>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="element in list.data | filter: list.search">
                <div class= "well well-sm">
                    <div class= "row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img ng-src="{{element.image_url}}" class= "img-rounded img-responsive well-image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h4>{{element.type}}</h4>
                            <p><strong>Locations:</strong>{{element.type}}</p>
                            <p><strong>Locations:</strong>{{element.size}}</p>
                            <p><strong>Locations:</strong>{{element.locations}}</p>
                            <p><strong>Locations:</strong>{{element.lifespan}}</p>
                            <p><strong>Locations:</strong>{{element.diet}}</p>

                            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
                                    data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#quiz-info"
                                    ng-click="list.changeActiveQuiz(element); list.dataService.getAllQ()"
                            >START</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal" id="quiz-info">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h2>{{list.activeInfobox.type}}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class ="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
                                <img ng-src="{{list.activeInfobox.image_url}}" class="img-rounded img-responsive">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row top-buffer" >
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p><strong>Locations:</strong>{{list.activeInfobox.locations}}</p>
                                <p><strong>Locations:</strong>{{list.activeInfobox.type}}</p>
                                <p><strong>Locations:</strong>{{list.activeInfobox.size}}</p>
                                <p><strong>Locations:</strong>{{list.activeInfobox.locations}}</p>
                                <p><strong>Locations:</strong>{{list.activeInfobox.lifespan}}</p>
                                <p><strong>Locations:</strong>{{list.activeInfobox.diet}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class ="col-xs-12 top-buffer">
                                <p>{{list.activeInfobox.description}}</p>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Bezár</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="quizController as quiz" ng-show="quiz.quizMetrics.quizActive">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <h4>Progress:</h4>
                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                    <button class="btn"
                            ng-repeat="question in quiz.dataService.quizQuestions"
                            ng-class="{'btn-info': question.selected !== null, 'btn-danger':question.selected === null}"
                            ng-click="quiz.setActiveQuestion($index)">
                            <span class = "glyphicon"
                                ng-class="{'glyphicon-pencil': question.selected !== null, 'glyphicon-question-sign': question.selected === null}"
                            ></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <h4>Legend:</h4>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-info">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                        </button>
                        <p>Answered</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
                        </button>
                        <p>Unanswered</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--progress area-->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="quiz.error">
                Hiba! Nem válaszoltál az összes kérdésre!
                <button class="close" ng-click="quiz.error = false">&times</button>
            </div>

            <h3>Question:</h3>
            <div class="well well-sm" ng-hide="quiz.finalise">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h4>
                            {{quiz.activeQuestion+1 + ". " + quiz.dataService.quizQuestions[quiz.activeQuestion].text }}
                        </h4>
                                <div class="row" ng-if="quiz.dataService.quizQuestions[quiz.activeQuestion].type ==='text' ">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="answer in quiz.dataService.quizQuestions[quiz.activeQuestion].possibilities">
                                        <h4 class="answer" ng-class="{'bg-info': $index === quiz.dataService.quizQuestions[quiz.activeQuestion].selected}"
                                        ng-click="quiz.selectAnswer($index)">
                                            {{answer.answer}}
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row" ng-if="quiz.dataService.quizQuestions[quiz.activeQuestion].type ==='image' ">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="answer in quiz.dataService.quizQuestions[quiz.activeQuestion].possibilities">
                                        <div class="image-answer"
                                        ng-class="{'image-selected': $index === quiz.dataService.quizQuestions[quiz.activeQuestion].selected}"
                                        ng-click="quiz.selectAnswer($index)">
                                            <img ng-src="{{answer.answer}}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="quiz.questionAnswered()">Tovább</button>
                <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right" method="get" th:href="@{/logout}">
                    <strong>Logout</strong>
                </a>
                </div>

            <div class="well well-sm" ng-show="quiz.finalise">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h3>Biztos el akarod küldeni a válaszaidat?</h3>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="quiz.finaliseAnswers()">Igen</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger"  ng-click="quiz.finalise = false">Nem</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="resultsController as results" ng-show="results.quizMetrics.resultsActive">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-8">
              <h2>Results:</h2>
              <div class="btn-toolbar">
                  <button class="btn"
                          ng-repeat="question in results.dataService.quizQuestions"
                          ng-class="{'btn-success': question.correct, 'btn-danger': !question.correct}"
                          ng-click="results.setActiveQuestion($index)">
                            <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-ok': question.correct, 'glyphicon-remove': !question.correct}"></span>
                  </button>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">
              <div class="row">
                  <h4>Legend:</h4>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <button class="btn btn-success">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                      </button>
                      <p>Answered</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <button class="btn btn-danger">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                      </button>
                      <p>Unanswered</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 top-buffer">
                <h2>Score: {{results.quizMetrics.numCorrect}} / {{results.dataService.quizQuestions.length}}</h2>
                <h2><strong>{{results.calculatePerc() | number:2}}%</strong></h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <h3>Questions:</h3>
            <div class="well well-sm">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h4>{{ results.activeQuestion+1 + ". " + results.dataService.quizQuestions[results.activeQuestion].text }}</h4>

                        <div class="row" ng-if="results.dataService.quizQuestions[results.activeQuestion].type === 'text'">
                            <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="answer in results.dataService.quizQuestions[results.activeQuestion].possibilities">
                                <h4 class="answer"
                                ng-class="results.getAnswerClass($index)">
                                    {{answer.answer}}
                                    <p class="pull-right" ng-show="$index !== results.quizMetrics.correctAnswers[results.activeQuestion] && $index === results.dataService.quizQuestions[results.activeQuestion].selected">Válaszod</p>
                                    <p class="pull-right" ng-show="$index === results.quizMetrics.correctAnswers[results.activeQuestion]">Helyes válasz</p>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row" ng-if="results.dataService.quizQuestions[results.activeQuestion].type === 'image'">
                            <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="answer in results.dataService.quizQuestions[results.activeQuestion].possibilities">
                                <div class="image-answer"
                                     ng-class="results.getAnswerClass($index)">
                                    <image ng-src="{{answer.answer}}"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--well-->

            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="results.reset()">Vissza</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>


<!--thid party js-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.js"></script>


<!--our app js-->
<script src="./js/app.js"></script>
<script src="./js/controller/list.js"></script>
<script src="./js/controller/quiz.js"></script>
<script src="./js/factory/quizMetrics.js"></script>
<script src="./js/controller/results.js"></script>
<script src="./js/factory/dataService.js"></script>


</body>
</html>




Error: dataService.init is not a function
reset@http://localhost:8080/js/controller/results.js:40:13
fn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.js line 14157 > Function:2:267
expensiveCheckFn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.js:15146:18
callback@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.js:24614:17
$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.js:16888:16
$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.js:16988:20
ngEventHandler/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.js:24619:17
defaultHandlerWrapper@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.js:3394:3
eventHandler@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.js:3382:9
```

If i use the getAllQ method instead of the init method, I still get this error getAllQ is not a function however other function declared like this are working.

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that the function `init` is not defined in the angular `factory`. The `DataFactory` function is returning an object `dataObj`, these properties become the exposed properties in the factory that is used in the controller. To be able to us `init` in the controller you would need to amend `dataObj` so that it is:

```
var dataObj = {
    init: init,
    quizData: quizData,
    quizQuestions: [],
    correctAnswers: []
};
```

Hope that helps.

Some additional reading on factories vs services in angularjs:

- https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html

Comment: Thank you for the question, I'll try it. Currently angular is still magic to me...

Comment: Not a problem. Just keep trying and you'll get it

Comment: Actually I tried and I don't get the error, but the function itself which is a REST call do not do anything... :/